# Actionsheet text is always grey (NSAttributedString.Key doesn't working)

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, actionsheet

I'm using a custom actionsheet with some text displaying. With XCode 11.3 I can't use NSAttributedString.Key.foreground. It used to work before the update, but now I can't find a solution.

[Screengrab with example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRqkr.jpg)

[image]

```
    let attributedMessageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: description,
        attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red
        ]
    )
```

If I'm trying to change a background color, it turns gray too.
Maybe someone already faced this problem?

Comment: bad practice to embed code with a picture. Please update your question and insert code with tag

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to use private API as they might change without notice. I guess you use something like this:

```
actionSheet.setValue(message, forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

that's why this doesn't work on iOS13.3. Unfortunately there is no legal way to change those color with the public APIs. But you're [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224830/ios-13-uialertcontroller-color-change-in-attributedmessage-and-attributedtitle) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992692/ios13-1-uialertcontroller-with-preferedstyle-actionsheet-cannot-change-titles#comment102416271_57992692) is good recommendation

Comment: Yep, you're right, it's a good idea to use a custom action sheet. Thanks a lot!